# Merging two dataframes pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 input files:

a) An original file ( orig_file.json ), containing records like this:

```
{"id": 1, "app": test_a, "description": test_app_a }
{"id": 2, "app": test_b, "description": test_app_b }
{"id": 3, "app": test_c, "description": test_app_c }
{"id": 4, "app": test_d, "description": test_app_d }
{"id": 5, "app": test_e, "description": test_app_e }
```

b) A 'deltas' file ( deltas_file.json ), containing records like this:

```
{"id": 1, "app": test_aaaxxx, "description": test_app_aaaxxx }
{"id": 6, "app": test_ffffff, "description": test_app_ffffff }
```

I am trying to merge two files( original + deltas ) in such way that an output like this results

```
{"id": 1, "app": test_aaaxxx, "description": test_app_aaaxxx }
{"id": 2, "app": test_b, "description": test_app_b }
{"id": 3, "app": test_c, "description": test_app_c }
{"id": 4, "app": test_d, "description": test_app_d }
{"id": 5, "app": test_e, "description": test_app_e }
{"id": 6, "app": test_ffffff, "description": test_app_ffffff }
```

*basically merging original file with deltas file by adding any new app and just update records for the ones that already exist.
.

I have tried to use different joins but could not get the solution.

Can someone guide me the approach to solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left outer join and coalesce:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *


deltas.join(origin, ["id"], "leftouter") \
  .select("id", 
      coalesce(deltas["app"], origin["app"]).alias("app"),
      coalesce(deltas["description"], origin["description"]).alias("description"))
```

Comment: when i run the above command, it shows an error that dataframe object is not callable.

Answer (score -2):

Try python panda merge.

```
import panda as pd
# create your data frames here
pd.merge(delta_frame,orig_frame)  # Try various required arguments in function
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: There are multiple options in pySpark which would not require a ```toPandas()``` operation in order to accomplish the merge. ```.join()``` likely being the most appropriate.